# Wrong result in my function for eulerProject

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to find solutions to euler-problem n°15.
http://projecteuler.net/problem=15
(Find the number of paths from the top left to the bottom right corners of a grid).

The first try wasn't successful, as I stored in a List every possible combination, I ended up with a heap problem (predictable, isn't it).

In the second try, I decided to count how many possible ways existed for every point in the grid.
For exemple (0,0) has a only way to be accessed, (1,1) has two (via (0,1) and another via (1,0)). For every point, we sum the possible ways of the two previous points.
As this seemed to be a great solution without much memory problem, I still don't get the right answer, can you give me hint of the origin of my mistake (because I assume I made a mistake, and not them obviously).

Snafucated sourcecode:

```
    @Test
public void testFoo() {
    long[][] grid = new long[20][20];
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        grid[0][i]=1;
        grid[i][0] =1;
    }
    int steps=1;
    while(steps<21){
        for(int i=steps; i<20; i++){
            grid[i][steps]= grid[i-1][steps]+grid[i][steps-1];
            grid[steps][i]= grid[i-1][steps]+grid[i][steps-1];
        }
        steps++;
    }
    System.out.println(grid[19][19]); //35345263800
}
```

Comment: Starting at `i=steps` means that you always have `i>=steps`, which means that you are looking only at the top-right half of the square.  Why not focus on getting the right answer for the 2x2 case first?

Comment: @Teepeemm The (2.2) digit looks exact (equals 2), and grid(3,3) = 6. In my loop, for step = n, I already calculated every part of the grid with i<n and j <n, so there is no point calculating them again.

Comment: You're right.  johnchen902 noticed what went wrong.  In fact, you have the correct answer for at 19x19 grid.

Comment: @Teepeemm My sincere apology, I didn't understand what you meant. The answer was indead wrong for a 2x2 case, because I needed a 3x3 grid. Thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `2 × 2` grid, there are `3 × 3` intersections, so you need an `3 × 3` array.

```
  0 1 2
0 ┌─┬─┐
1 ├─┼─┤
2 └─┴─┘
```

So for a `20 × 20` grid, you need an `21 × 21` array.

---

Another solution: using combination in math, the answer is [image: combination 40 20].

Comment: WoW. This is why it failed obviously. Thanks a lot!!